# Error in python string

Tags: python

when I type this code in python it shows this error

```
>>> 'Ahmed' + \t 'Ashraf '
```

> SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

what does this error mean ??

Comment: That means there was an unexpected character. `'Ahmed' + '\t' + 'Ashraf'` should work.

Comment: This question was caused by a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\t` escape sequence has to be inside a string literal, so the correct syntax is:

```
'Ahmed' + '\t' + 'Ashraf '
```

Outside a string literal, `\` is used to indicate that you're continuing a statement on the next line, so it's called the *line continuation character*. It should only be followed by a newline, e.g.

```
>>> var1 = 'Ahmed' + \
'Ashraf'
```

If it's followed by some other character, such as `t` in your example, you get an error.

Comment: Rather than `'Ahmed' + '\t' + 'Ashraf '` you may as well directly go `'Ahmed\tAshraf '`

Comment: @Julien Of course, but then I wouldn't demonstrate how to concatenate strings. In his real application there's likely to be variables involved.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with the format string.

```
>>> '%s\t%s' %('Ahmed','Ashraf')
'Ahmed\tAshraf'
>>>
```